# Trigger to update a materialized view once after relevant transaction?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, materialized-view

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.

I have a materialized view to support full-text search across two tables, which I'll call `posts` and `tags`. The tables are infrequently updated and frequently searched.

I'm trying to find a good strategy to run `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW post_search`.

The ideal solution would be a trigger like this: **at the end of (or after) any transaction that modifies `posts`, `tags` and/or `posts_tags` (join table), refresh the materialized view exactly once**.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 12):

## An OK solution using triggers

This is what I'm doing now. It's not *exactly* what I wanted because the trigger fires once per statement instead of once per transaction. But it works for now.

(In the future, we're thinking of using an **actual table** for search instead of a materialized view, and updating individual relevant rows via triggers instead of refreshing an entire matview.)

Create a function to refresh the materialized view concurrently:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_post_search()
  RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS $$
  BEGIN
  REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY post_search;
  RETURN NULL;
  END $$;
```

And create a trigger for each of the underlying tables:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER refresh_post_search
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE OR TRUNCATE
  ON posts
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE refresh_post_search();

  CREATE TRIGGER refresh_post_search
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE OR TRUNCATE
  ON posts_tags
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE refresh_post_search();

  CREATE TRIGGER refresh_post_search
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE OR TRUNCATE
  ON tags
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE refresh_post_search();
```

Comment: I'm considering a similar approach, I'm just curious how this worked out, or if you had any comments I should consider.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I wrote up the details at http://nathanmlong.com/2018/01/fast-fulltext-search-with-ecto-and-postgresql/

Comment: `we're thinking of using an actual table for search instead of a materialized view` This still would not solve your nitpick of it firing by once per statement, not per transaction, would it? In other words, what do you think is wrong with the materialized view approach?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer to my own question in your blogpost: `The remaining downside is that recalculating the entire materialized view when only one row needs to change is a bit wasteful.`

Comment: what is the difference between running for each row and for each statement for insert and update and delete queries? i know that truncate only works with for each statement

Answer (score 5):

Well, likely you're doing it wrong. While the verb `REFRESH` may connote otherwise, you're actually rewriting the table when you run it. That kind of workload is heavy to run in a trigger (though you could).

That doesn't make much sense. You either

1. Don't want a `MATERIALIZED VIEW;`
2. Want a strategy to `REFRESH` during down time, or off time, or periodically.

The second one is *usually* done with

1. a simple cron, [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) or the like
2. at the end of import

Normally, you either need

- Always-right: use a plain view.
- Periodically right: use a materialized view.
- Fluid and right: you may check into [`NOTIFY/EVENT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) or time-series databases

It's quite possible that a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` simply isn't what you want.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that I do want a materialized view. I want to run full-text queries against the combined, weighted `ts_vector`s of `posts.title` and `string_agg(tags.title)`. Using a materialized view instead of a subquery sped this up 10x. Not using one means building the same vectors on every query.

Comment: I'm not convinced anyway, can I see your query `\d` on all tables with a tsvector?

Comment: As for running `REFRESH` on a cron job, that could work. But it seems a bit silly to be checking (eg) every hour for changes when I'm in charge of the system that produces them, doesn't it?

Comment: Sure, again, it's somewhat likely that a trigger would do *exactly* what you want if you need event driven-recalculation of a table -- that goes back to a materialized view not being what you want. But, I'm not convinced you need a view either. If the query is slow, show it and let's take a look at it. I need to see more information. Paste the query the MATERIALIZED VIEW runs, an explain analyze plan, and the schema for the tables.

Comment: The actual data is `recipes` rather than `posts`. The materialized view is `      CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW recipe_search AS
      SELECT
      recipes.id AS id,
      recipes.title AS title,
      (
      setweight(to_tsvector(recipes.title), 'A') ||
      setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(string_agg(tags.value_slug, ' '), ' ')), 'B')
      ) AS document
      FROM recipes
      LEFT JOIN recipes_tags ON recipes_tags.recipe_id = recipes.id
      LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = recipes_tags.tag_id
      GROUP BY recipes.id
`

Comment: so you want the mat view to refresh when the recipe's tags change?

Comment: Yes, or when the recipe's title is edited, or when new recipes are added... any change to either of the two data tables or the join table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68484/discussion-between-nathan-long-and-evan-carroll-qwer-hjkl).